# diff directories, excluding one folder inside

Tags: linux, bash, diff

I think I have two directories with the same content, but I want to check it.

Also, I want to exclude a folder that is inside both directories.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 64):

command line:

```
diff --exclude=direxclude -r dir1 dir2
```

openSUSE 12.1: ok.

```
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp> md dir1
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp> md dir2
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp> cd dir2
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir2> md 10
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir2> md 11
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir2> md 12
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir2> md 14
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir2> cd ..
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp> cd dir1
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir1> md 15
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir1> md 11
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir1> md 12
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir1> md 17
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp/dir1> cd ..
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp> diff --exclude="11" -r dir1 dir2
Only in dir2: 10
Only in dir2: 14
Only in dir1: 15
Only in dir1: 17
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp> diff --exclude=11 -r dir1 dir2
Only in dir2: 10
Only in dir2: 14
Only in dir1: 15
Only in dir1: 17
sttr@linux-sgfb:/tmp>
```

CentOS 6.3 64: ok.

```
[root@local tmp]# mkdir dir1
....
```

Ubuntu 12.04 TLS: ok.

[image: Ubuntu 12.04 TLS]

Comment: @STTR sorry but it didn't work

Comment: @user35538 Could you please be more specific? What didn't work, what did you enter?

Comment: `diff --exclude="direxclude" -r dir1 dir2` variant?

Comment: version OS test?

Comment: @STTR Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @user35538 Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/548476/searching-subdirectories-one-one-level-down-for-file

Comment: Works at OS X 10.10.

Comment: @STTR I understand that `-x foldername` can be used to explicitly list all folders that shouldn't be used for comparison. Supposed I want to exclude all `.git` files from being used in the `diff`, but there could be multiple `.git` folders across multiple directories. how would you do that?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. It runs without error but still considers the directory that I want to exclude.

Comment: Adding the option `-N` to `diff` makes it also treat files that are present only n one side to be treated as empty on the other side, so that a complete patch will be produced. Otherwise, `diff` will just say that the file is only in one side but will not print out it's content.

Comment: This answer doesn't really answers the question. It asks a way to ignore folder in both directories when diffing not to ignore ALL folders matching some name..

Comment: I've tried that and it worked for me. I was even able to exclude multiple folders just by repeating the exclude flag: `diff --exclude=foo --exclude=bar -r dir1 dir2`.