# List subdirectories one level down that do not contain a certain file

Tags: linux

How can I find all subdirectories in a directory (only 1 level down) that do not contain a given file ?

Comment: How have you tried doing this?  Do you want for perform this with Bash? I.e. through the command line.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/196960/find-directories-that-dont-contain-a-file

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to accomplish this with [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find).

Approach 1 is less hacky and will work well with strange directory names (e.g., directory names containing newlines), but approach 2 should be faster if there are a lot of directories.

### Approach 1

#### Command

```
find DIR -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -not -exec test -f {}/FILENAME \; \
    -print | sort
```

#### How it works

- `find DIR -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` finds all directories (`-type d`) in *DIR*, with depth 1.
- `-not -exec test -f {}/FILENAME \;` is true if and only if a file called *FILENAME* could not be found in the currently processed directory (`{}`).
- `-print` will output the desired directory names.
- If desired, `sort` will sort the output alphabetically.

### Approach 2

#### Command

```
( find DIR -type f -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name FILENAME -printf "%h\n" ; \
    find DIR -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ) | sort | uniq -u
```

#### How it works

- `find DIR -type f -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -name FILENAME` finds all files (`-type f`) called *FILENAME* in the subdirectories of *DIR* (files of directories of depth 1 have depth 2).
- `-print "%h\n"` print the names of the directories containing files named *FILENAME*, followed by a newline.
- `find DIR -type d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` list all directories (`-type d`) in *DIR*, with depth 1.
- `sort` sorts the output alphabetically (output must be sorted when piping to `uniq`).
- `uniq -u` prints only unique lines.

  Every subdirectory of *DIR* gets listed at least once, but those that contain a file called *FILENAME* get listed twice. `uniq -u` eliminates the latter kind.

Answer (score 1):

Directly in shell script:

```
for i in DIRECTORY/*/; do [ -f "$i/FILENAME" ] || basename "$i"; done
```

- `for i in DIRECTORY/*/` uses shell expansion to safely (shouldn't be any problems with strange directory names) give all sub directories of a specific directory. Note the trailing slash to only give the directories.
- `[ -f "$i/FILENAME" ]` returns true if the file named `FILENAME` exists in the directory in this iteration. The `||` operator makes the following command run if the first one returned false, i.e. only if the file did *not* exist in the directory.
- `basename "$i"` prints the directory name (if the file name wasn't found therein). If you want the full path and not just the directory name, substitute `basename` for `echo` or `readlink -f` or something else per preference.

If you also want to include hidden directories, run (in Bash)

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

before the command.